Buscar un valor dentro de un dataframe en Python
Con Python estoy manipulando una hoja Excel, tiene el número de filas y columnas variables.
La importo a Python como un dataframe, pero ahora necesito saber la fila y la columna que tiene un valor en concreto.
He estado mirando y todos los ejemplos que veo es sabiendo la columna que está, pero en mi caso puede variar, por lo que necesito saber la fila y la columna.
Me explico mejor, Cuando importo el archivo excel a Phyton lo que obtengo es un dataframe de este estilo
Gracias, me explico mejor... Cuando importo el archivo excel a Phyton lo que obtengo es un dateframe de este estilo
Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1  ... Unnamed: 7 Unnamed: 8
0          NaN        NaN  ...        NaN        NaN
1          NaN     Código  ...       Fe24       Mz24
2          NaN   686077.9  ...        ---        ---
3          NaN   720932.4  ...        ---        ---
4          NaN   686078.6  ...          2          4
5          NaN   727435.3  ...          1        ---
6          NaN   686083.0  ...        ---        ---
7          NaN   720940.9  ...        ---        ---
8          NaN   686084.7  ...          2          2
9          NaN   727437.7  ...        ---          2
10         NaN   703867.2  ...        ---        ---
11         NaN   703869.6  ...          4          3
12         NaN   706633.0  ...          6          5
El número de filas y columnas es variable, pero necesito averiguar donde está la palabra código de una forma optima. Porque lo he conseguido recorriendo toda la tabla por fila y columna hasta que el campo sea igual...
Pero me gustaría hacerlo de una forma más optima y seguro que hay alguna función que me dice donde está la palabra "Código", para después yo poder trabajar a partir de ahí...
gracias..

¿Has probado esto? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53979441

Necesitamos saber que has intentado, y algo de codigo que uses, mas que nada para tener una base y poder guiarte.

Me funciona buscando por cada uno de los elementos recorriendo toda la tabla pero ¿no hay una busqueda más óptima?

No especificas si el valor puede estar repetido o no, pero una opción genérica puede ser la siguiente:
Partamos de un dataframe de ejemplo:
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Col_1": [2, 3, 2, 7],
    "Col_2": [0, 6, 3 ,2]
    })

>>> df

   Col_1  Col_2
0      2      0
1      3      6
2      2      3
3      7      2

Puedes filtrar las celdas que contienen un determinado valor simplemente con df == valor:
>>> df == 2

   Col_1  Col_2
0   True  False
1  False  False
2   True  False
3  False   True

Para obtener la fila y la columna puedes usar numpy.nonzero:
>>> (df == 2).to_numpy().nonzero()

(array([0, 2, 3]), array([0, 0, 1]))

como se puede ver, retorna dos arrays con los indices de las celdas donde hay valores diferentes de cero (True). El primero contiene los indices de las filas y el segundo los de las columnas. Es decir, el valor 2 aparece en [0, 0], [2, 0] y [3, 1].
Para obtener los valores del indice/columna del Dataframe basta con usar los atributos index y columns del mismo. Todo junto:
>>> valor = 2
>>> rows, cols = (df == valor).to_numpy().nonzero()
>>> locs = tuple((df.index[idx], df.columns[col]) for idx, col in zip(rows, cols))

>>> locs

((0, 'Col_1'), (2, 'Col_1'), (3, 'Col_2'))

El resultado es una tupla de tuplas en la que cada tupla interna representa una celda donde se ha encontrado el valor, con su indice y columna.
Para valor = 3 nos genera:
((1, 'Col_1'), (2, 'Col_2'))

para valor = 7:
((3, 'Col_1'),)

y para valor = 13
()

Edición
Adaptado para obtener una salida similar a la que planteas y para tus datos, puedes hacer algo como:
valor_buscar = "Código"
for f, c in zip(*(dfa == valor_buscar).to_numpy().nonzero()):
    print(f"El valor {valor_buscar} se encuentra en la fila {f}, columna {c}")


Gracias, me explico mejor...

mucho mejor, muchísimas gracias...

He encontrado esta solución, me parece un poco, poco optimizado, pero por ahora funciona...
En el fondo, recorrer toda la tabla
import pandas as pd
FA = pd.ExcelFile("excel.xlsx")
dfa = pd.read_excel(FA)
print (dfa)
f=0
c=0
# Valor a buscar
valor_buscar = "Código"

for f in range(len(dfa.index)):
    for c in range(len(dfa.columns)):
        if dfa.iloc[f, c] == valor_buscar:
            print(f"El valor {valor_buscar} se encuentra en la fila {f}, columna {c}")
            break

El resultado es algo así...
Unnamed: 0 Unnamed: 1  ... Unnamed: 7 Unnamed: 8
0          NaN        NaN  ...        NaN        NaN
1          NaN        NaN  ...        NaN        NaN
2          NaN        NaN  ...        NaN        NaN
3          NaN     Código  ...       Fe24       Mz24
4          NaN   686077.9  ...        ---        ---
5          NaN   720932.4  ...        ---        ---
6          NaN   686078.6  ...          2          4
7          NaN   727435.3  ...          1        ---
El valor Código se encuentra en la fila 3, columna 1
No sé si hay una opción más optima...
gracias
